# python exception handler to recommend package

Tags: python

I would like to have python recommend a python package in the event of an import error.

I tried:

```
except ImportError as e:
     sys.exit("'Error: Try sudo pip install %s'" % e)
```

but this is the output:

```
'Error: Try sudo pip install No module named 'Crypto''
```

I would like the output to be:

```
'Error: Try sudo pip install Crypto'
```

how can I do that?

Update:
it pretty hacky, but here is something that seems to work:

```
except ImportError as e:
     e = e.replace("No module named '", "")
     e = e.replace("'", "")
     sys.exit("'Error: Try sudo pip install %s'" % e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImportError.name`

```
>>> try:
...     import fakecrypto
... except ImportError as e:
...     ex = e
... 
>>> dir(ex)
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', 
'__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
'__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__',
'__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', 'args',
'msg', 'name', 'path', 'with_traceback']
>>> ex.name
'fakecrypto'
```